# Can't bevel edge

Tags: modeling, edges, bevel

I'm modelling a lego brick and I cannot bevel this edge. The edge still stays sharp. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I'm only new to blender.[image]This is the blender file: [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two models on the same place. The bevel works, the sharp edge belongs to an other model.